Shopify api not returning results with correct parameters
I am making a discord bot and I have two commands, one of which I want to return a specific order, the bot deploys the commands with deploy-commands.js(not really relevant) and this specific command is called order.js, here it is:
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');

const { createAdminRestApiClient } = require('@shopify/admin-api-client');


const client = createAdminRestApiClient({
  storeDomain: 'x.myshopify.com',
  apiVersion: '2024-04',
  accessToken: 'y',
});

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('order')
        .setDescription('Returns a order with a given order id.')
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName('id')
                .setDescription('The id of the order you want info about!')
                .setRequired(true)),
        
    async execute(interaction) {

        const orderId = interaction.options.getInteger('id');
        const response = await client.get(`orders/${orderId}`);
        console.log(response)
        if (response.ok) {
            const body = await response.json();
            console.log(body);
        }
    },
};

All this seems like it should work, yet when I input a valid order ID or product ID I've tried both endpoints, neither of them work. Any ideas why? Thanks!
The output is:
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 404,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 530421.735029,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 530421.735029,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 26,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(25) {
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'transfer-encoding' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'x-sorting-hat-podid' => [Object],
      'vary' => [Object],
      'referrer-policy' => [Object],
      'x-frame-options' => [Object],
      'x-request-id' => [Object],
      'server-timing' => [Object],
      'x-shopify-stage' => [Object],
      'content-security-policy' => [Object],
      'x-content-type-options' => [Object],
      'x-download-options' => [Object],
      'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies' => [Object],
      'x-xss-protection' => [Object],
      'x-envoy-upstream-service-time' => [Object],
      'x-dc' => [Object],
      'cf-cache-status' => [Object],
      'report-to' => [Object],
      'nel' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object],
      'cf-ray' => [Object],
      'content-encoding' => [Object],
      'alt-svc' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}

Also I tried this endpoint

By simply changing my code to this:
async execute(interaction) {

        const orderId = interaction.options.getInteger('id');
        const response = await client.get(`products/count`);
        console.log(response)
        if (response.ok) {
            const body = await response.json();
            console.log(body);
        }
    },

So I can no longer have the possibility of my order id being wrong, I know it doesn't make sense to have a order command output the product count but it still returns this:
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 404,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 559095.311115,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 559095.311115,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 0,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(25) {
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'transfer-encoding' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'x-sorting-hat-podid' => [Object],
      'vary' => [Object],
      'referrer-policy' => [Object],
      'x-frame-options' => [Object],
      'x-request-id' => [Object],
      'server-timing' => [Object],
      'x-shopify-stage' => [Object],
      'content-security-policy' => [Object],
      'x-content-type-options' => [Object],
      'x-download-options' => [Object],
      'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies' => [Object],
      'x-xss-protection' => [Object],
      'x-envoy-upstream-service-time' => [Object],
      'x-dc' => [Object],
      'cf-cache-status' => [Object],
      'report-to' => [Object],
      'nel' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object],
      'cf-ray' => [Object],
      'content-encoding' => [Object],
      'alt-svc' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}


"neither of them work"... what do they do instead? What does your console.log(response) show?

Sorry I forgot I didn't add the output, I edited it now

The 404 response status suggests that the order with the provided ID doesn't exist

I added one more edit where even where there's no parameter it doesn't return the right thing

have tried to update the endpoint from products/count to admin/products/count?
